# COPY csv file into PostGIS table

Tags: python, postgis

I have two csv files containing the actual coordinates of two polygons. I need to copy the contents of csv files into PostGIS table named 'sample'. I need to find the intersection of two polygons and the area of intersection. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBz9r.png)

I am new in PostGIS. Please help me.

Comment: Is a quite broad topic...What do you have already tried? Did you read this? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming WGS84:

first create the table

```
create table sample (lat float, lon float);
```

then insert the csv into the table (might take some adjusting with delimiters).

```
copy sample from 'path_to_csv' delimiter ';' csv;
```

then convert lat lon to points (thus assuming WGS84, SRID 4326):

```
alter table sample add column geom geometry(point, 4326) 
    using st_setsrid(st_makepoint(lon, lat),4326);
```

then create the polygon from the point table by first creating a linestring, then a polygon. Make sure the linestring is closed, this means the first point must be equal to the last point!

```
select st_makepolygon(st_makeline(geom)) geom 
    into polygon1 
    from sample;
```

To get the intersection area of the two polygons:

```
select filename, st_makepolygon(st_makeline(geom)) geom 
    into polygons
    from sample
    group by filename;
select st_area(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom)) 
    from polygons a, polygons b
    where a.filename == 'part1' and b.filename == 'part2'
```

Comment: I inserted a new field 'filename' in the first csv file and entered its value as 'part1' and later(second csv file) indicated by 'part2'.I clustered the table entries based on its 'filename'. I need to find the area of intersection of part1 cluster and part2 cluster.

Comment: I added a section to get to the intersection area of the two polygons.